# Adjust size of an image of a range copied from Excel into Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, html-email

I copy a range from Excel into Outlook email. The image comes in too small.

The `.Width` and `.Height` don't change the image.

```vb
Dim OutApp2 As Object
Dim OutMail2 As Object
Dim table2 As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim tableoosinst As Range
Dim pic2 As Picture
Dim WordDoc2
 
Set OutApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail2 = OutApp2.CreateItem(0)
 
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ISK VS OSA Chart")
Set table2 = ws2.Range("E1:Ab34")
ws2.Activate
table2.Copy
Set pic2 = ws2.Pictures.Paste
pic2.Cut
 
'create email
On Error Resume Next

Dim name As String
name = slItem2.name

With OutMail2
    .Subject = name & " Score Card"
    .Display 
       
    Set WordDoc2 = OutMail2.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
    With WordDoc2.Range    
        .pasteandFormat wdChartPicture
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width 100
        .Height = 100
        .InsertParagraphAfter
    End With
    
    .HTMLBody = "Hi Team, <p> Please see the table below" & .HTMLBody
    .Save
    .Close (olSave)
End With

On Error GoTo 0
        
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing
```

I tried pretty much everything. The aspect ratio still comes in locked on the Outlook email.

If the image being copied is too large the other option I was thinking was to copy multiple separate images in the Outlook email, but I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is 100% inappropriate here. While debugging it doubly so.

Comment: So what are the attributes set on the img tag? Also, you should never concatenate two HTML strings - they must be merged.

Comment: The on error is for a different part of the code that if not on here. that part of the code seems to work fine.

Comment: Dim OutApp2 As Object
 Dim OutMail2 As Object
 Dim table2 As Range
 Dim ws2 As Worksheet
 Dim tableoosinst As Range
 Dim pic2 As Picture
 Dim WordDoc2
 
 
 Set OutApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail2 = OutApp2.CreateItem(0)
 
 Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ISK VS OSA Chart")
 Set table2 = ws2.Range("E1:Ab34")
 ws2.Activate
 table2.Copy
 Set pic2 = ws2.Pictures.Paste
 pic2.Cut     

These are all the attributes that didn't paste correctly over. I apologize. I am still relatively new to vba

Comment: As you can see, code does not paste well in the comments. Instead, edit your question.

Comment: Have you tried using other arguments like the `wdFormatOriginalFormatting` one?

Comment: The scope of `On Error Resume Next` in the code shown includes the lines that attempt to set image size.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest merging your message body content and keep the result HTML markup well-formed:

```
.HTMLBody = "Hi Team, <p> Please see the table below" & .HTMLBody
```

That means you need to find the `<body>` and insert your text right after it, but not concatenate strings together. You should set a well-formed HTML markup to the `HTMLBody` property and never rely on Outlook to handle this part for you if you want to get stable results in the message body.

Second, you need to check out the original image size - whether it corresponds to the pasted one. Try to play with different arguments, for example, you may try passing the `wdFormatOriginalFormatting` value instead or just use the [Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.paste) method.

Third, as a an alternative implementation you can save the image to the disk from where you could attach it to the message in Outlook (see `Attachments.Add`) and use it in the message body. For example:

```
attachment = MailItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1")
MailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:MyId1""></body></html>"
```